# SQL Server stops sending records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

We have a very complex analysis process with multiple variables and thousands of records that would normally generate trillions of permutation records in `tempdb`.  Through preprocessing and dynamic SQL we've been able to complete an analysis in a few seconds and with only a few thousand records in `tempdb` (instead of trillions).

The code has been in use for several years.  Today one of the variable inputs grew to double its traditional size and SQL Server was uanble to finish running the code.  It will just stop sending data for one of the preprocessing steps.  The full code is much to lengthy and complex to include here, but to illustrate what is happening:

```
/* Lots of SQL code */

print 'debug 1'

select distinct field
from   #table

print 'debug 2'

select   several..fields
from     many..tables..joined..with..temp..tables
where    multiple..conditions
group by several..fields

print 'debug 3'
```

If we execute the code in SSMS (running on the DB server), we can simply run the code down to the `print 'debug 2'` line and the are 330 records returned from the `select distinct field` statement instantly.

If we run all the code, only 290-325 (or so) records are returned from the `select distinct field` statement, and then the database server's CPU starts to thrash.  It will never return the rest of the 330 records and `debug 2` is never printed to the *Messages* tab/window.  Even when we abort the query after running for hours, there are fewer than 330 records in the *Result* tab/window and `debug 2` is not printed.

It's like the second `select` statement makes SQL Server unable to finish returning all of the rows for the first `select` statement.

I compared the query plan of both (with and without the last statement) and they are identical up to the `print 'debug 2'` line.  I tried adding indexes to the #temp tables, updating statistics in the db, and moving the last `select` statement to a stored procedure to help isolate the code.  Nothing helps.

Has anyone seen Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) just stop sending records during the middle of executing a SQL statement?  What did you do to fix it?

Comment: I've never seen it but I haven't been using SQL Server for very long.  How many lines is the query between debug 2 and debug 3?  Also, sorry if this is a newbie question, but the variable that doubled in size, is it put into another variable that is not typed to accommodate the newly doubled size?

Comment: @bf2020 - Good questions.  There are only three lines of code that go in between.  They open a cursor and start cursoring through the records.  The variable that doubled in size is a dataset with twice as many records as usual.  All variable are typed appropriately and no data is being truncated.

Comment: Have you tried to add transactions to the cursor?

Comment: @VladimirOselsky - I did not try adding transactions yet.  Good suggestion!

Comment: So, because it wouldn't work, the end users reorganized the data so make it work with fewer records in the input variables (so they could get their work done).  In other words, the inputs have changed enough now that I cannot duplicate the issue anymore.  If/when it happens again, I'll try the final cursor in a transaction and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the data is stuck in a buffer somewhere to me.
Replace the `PRINT`s with `RaisError('Debug n', 0, 0) WITH NOWAIT` and see if that changes things.

PS: Your intro made me really, really, really curious for the actual code =P

Comment: This is an interesting debugging technique.  Thank you.